# Implementing __add__ magic method to allow `sum` to operate on objects

Tags: python

I'm defining a class `Foo` with an `__add__` method:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.data + other.data
```

The `data` attribute is to hold strings *only*.

Ultimate goal is to pass a list/iterable of `Foo` objects to a sum method to concatenate strings:

```
In [580]: s = [Foo('foo'), Foo('bar'), Foo('baz')] 

In [581]: sum(s)
```

Expected:

```
foobarbaz
```

Actual:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-581-4c1cdc765951> in <module>()
----> 1 sum(s)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Foo'
```

I thought `sum` calls `object.__add__` to sum the two methods together. I know I can solve this another way (possibly with `functools.reduce`) but is there a way I can get this to work with `sum`?

Edit: Forgot to mention, tried this:

```
In [582]: sum(s, Foo(''))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-582-e3eeba9a6d93> in <module>()
----> 1 sum(s, Foo(''))

TypeError: Can't convert 'Foo' object to str implicitly
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass an initial value to `sum`.  Since your class only supports adding to other instances of the same class, you'd have to specify an "empty" instance as the initial value:

```
sum(s, Foo(''))
```

However, your class also has a problem: it only allows adding Foo instances to other Foo instances, but the addition returns a string, not a Foo instance.  So you can't add more than two Foos, even "manually":

```
>>> Foo('a') + Foo('b') + Foo('c')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    Foo('a') + Foo('b') + Foo('c')
TypeError: must be str, not Foo
```

To fix this, you need to make your `__add__` return a Foo:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return Foo(self.data + other.data)
```

Then when you do `sum(s, Foo(''))`, what you will get is not the string `foobarbaz`, but a Foo instance whose `.data` attribute is `'foobarbaz'`.

Comment: Sorry, check my edit. Tried this and got `TypeError: Can't convert 'Foo' object to str implicitly`. Something wrong on my end?

Comment: Thanks. It works now. But I'd have to do `sum(s, Foo('')).data`. No way round this... I suppose?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ: Not really.  You could give your class a `__str__` or `__repr__` method so the result is displayed in the interactive shell, but the result still has to be a Foo, not a "real" string.  You can't subclass from `str` because that will cause `sum` to again complain if you use it on Foo instances.

Answer (score 1):

`__add__` must return `Foo(self.data + other.data)`.

As a rule of thumb, the `__methods__` should return objects of type `type(self)`, although this is not always true. E.g. what would you expect `Int + Int` or `Float + Float` to return?